# OS X Lion - Installing Oracle 10g Standard Edition

Tags: macos, osx-lion, .bash-profile, oracle-10g

I'm trying to install Oracle 10g on to OS X Lion. I have previous achieved this on Snow Leopard with the following [tutorial](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).

The issue I'm having is that the ulimit settings in the `oracle/.bash_profile` cannot be modified.

I have the following in the bash_profile:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export ORACLE_BASE=$HOME
umask 022
# must match `sysctl kern.maxprocperuid`
ulimit -Hu 512
ulimit -Su 512
# must match `sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc`
ulimit -Hn 10240
ulimit -Sn 10240
```

Upon applying the bash_profile settings `. ~/.bash_profile` I get the following error:

```
-bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot be modify limit: Invalid argument
```

This then results in `$ sqlplus / as sysdba` not functioning correctly with a `Segmentation fault: 11`

The output of `$ ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 512
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

If any one knows how I can apply these ulimit settings to the oracle user I have created to allow me to install sqlplus and therefore create a db, that would be great.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to install it yet.

Comment: @sathya any explanation as to why?

Comment: from what I've read Lion brings in soem changes which breaks things - like setting up of ulimit

Comment: @sathya do you have the links, wouldn't mind reading up on that

Comment: ye, have a look at this thread http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2785278

Comment: Just an update on this.  I have found that the subtle differences found in oracle versions between Mac OS X and Linux has now pushed me to install a VM to mirror a production server setup as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to compile and install oracle and sqlplus on leopard and after moving the pieces to lion? e.g. sqlplus, tnsnames, oracle and so on in bin folder?

I found a [similar solution here](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) for snow leopard (the problem of segmentation was that binaries were compiled in 32bit mode under leopard then ported to 64bit snow leopard or something  similar..)

Answer (score 0):

The ulimit problem is because the `kern.maxprocperuid` Kernel parameter changed its default value to 709 in Lion (at least that was the default on my MacBook Air). As pointed out in the comment in the profile script, the values for:

```
ulimit -Hu 512
ulimit -Su 512
```

must match the `kern.maxprocperuid` Kernel parameter value. You can check this value with:

```
$ sysctl kern.maxprocperuid
```

In my case the default was 709, so that's what I put in my `.bash_profile` script:

```
ulimit -Hu 709
ulimit -Su 709
```

As for the segmentation fault when running `sqlplus`, I haven't found a solution for that. I can't get `netca` to run properly either. These would seem to be more serious issues!

Comment: helps if i read my own comments `# must match 'sysctl kern.maxprocperuid'`in my .bash_profile, will try this out and let you know how i get on

Comment: you'll get past the `.bash_profile` issue, but the "Segmentation Fault: 11" error is a showstopper that no one has managed to solve AFAIK. I've resorted to running Oracle in a Linux virtual machine on my Mac and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I had [posted a blog](http://techno-overload.blogspot.com/2011/02/oracle-database-10204-on-mac-os-x-snow.html) that might help.

It should work on Snow Leopard and hopefully also LION.

Comment: As per my comments on the initial post I was already using the http://blog.rayapps.com/ references that your blog cites.  I don't believe there is anything new that would help in this situation.